# Open and closed sets (accumulation points and inner points)

Tags: general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm really confused about topology in general.

Consider the set $A = (0, 1]$ in the space of real numbers

Now I understand that $1$ is not an inner point of A since $1 + \epsilon \notin A$, also
$1$ is accumulation point since $\lim 1 + 1/n = 1$

Why is $0$ not an accumulation point then? Since $\lim 1/n = 0$

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: $0$ **is** an accumulation point of $A$, though $0\not\in A$

Comment: You are asking about topological properties of a set $A$ in a topological space $X$, but you did not specify the space $X$. $1$ is not an inner point of $A$ in $ℝ$, but it is an inner point of $A$ in $A$.

Comment: @user87690 yes you are right I meant A as a subset of R

Comment: @J.W.Tanner so in order for the set to be closed $0 \in A$ would need to be true right?

Comment: yes, in the topological space $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology

Comment: @J.W.Tanner alright that helped me out (I somehow oversaw that fact while studying), go ahead and post it as an answer if you want I''ll mark it accepted, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology, $0$ is an accumulation point of $A=(0,1],$ though $0\not\in A$.

Because of that, $A$ is not closed.